# eclipse plugin adding to the right click menu

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am new to plugins, but I would like to make a plugin that would add an option in the right click menu of the editor.This option would add comments at certain points.
How I should go about doing this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this, you can already add comments in the files. Single-line: `// ....` Multiline: `/** .... **/`

Comment: There is a certain format of comments that i need to add to every file i make, and this process can be automated.

Comment: Modifying a Java source file in a plugin requires detailed knowledge of the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) If you haven't done an Eclipse plugin before this is a hard place to start.